# How to get the header, the same style and full width as the footer here

Tags: html, css, layout, bigcommerce

I am playing around with bigcommerce at the moment and I am trying to recreate the footer structure for the header. You can see here:

http://thespeedfactory.mybigcommerce.com/

If you look at the footer, how it is full width but the content is central within it.

I want the header to be exactly the same, black with pink/white highlights.

Ive tried moving around the structure within bigcommerce, but I am having a brain failure in getting it to do and look how I want despite knowing it is based around containers and margins.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: If you inspect the website you'll see that under the body there are two divs. One for the Header and content and one for the footer. Try to replicate that on your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want:

- the header (#Header) to span the entire width of the page
- the footer (#ContainerFooter) to span the entire width of the page
- the header (and footer to have the same styling (colors, etc.)
- the content area (#Wrapper) to stay a fixed width and centered on the page

To do this, add the following css:

```
#Container {width:100%;}
#Header {width:100%; margin:0, auto;}
```

The above css allows the header (by way of its parent container) to stretch the width of the browser page. You'll notice #Wrapper is shifted to the left. Add this:

```
#Wrapper {margin:auto;)
```

This centers the #Wrapper.

Your structure should be in place and now you can add your colors, etc. to the #Header to make it match the footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic html/css. 

 Just create a div, place a container in it and start styling.

HTML:

```
<div id="header"> 
    <div id="container">
        <p>content</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
    background:black;
    position:absolute;
    border-top:3px solid #ff25a7;
}
#container {
    width:90%;
    height:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#container p {
    font-size:30px;
    padding:10px;
    color: #ff25a7;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sga2m/1/) to help you get started.

Answer (score -1):

You can try giving the header the same class as the footer and afterwards (if the footer's position is `absolute bottom`), set the `position` to `absolute` `top:0px;`